# Reporting services RDLC legend coloring issue

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, colors, rdlc

I'm getting some weird coloring issues in a reporting services graph. As you can see from the picture I have it set to color my series and the coloring in the graph area is correct but the legend shows "Red" and "Green" as black bars. My data set is returning full HTML color codes e.g. "#00FF00" for green. How do I get the legend to display the correct color?

I can't seem to make sense of which colors aren't showing correctly either. If I have a drastically different data set different colors will be shown incorrectly and different numbers of them could be incorrect.

[image: Reporting Services Issue]

EDIT: adding info for commenters

The report is being populated from an object data source. My data object is:

```
public class GenericBrandRatingDataObject
{
    public string RatingName { get; set; }
    public string RatingColorCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the first 10 records of a potential data set:

```
Brown                 #996633        2010-08-09
Subcontractor Only    #808000        2010-08-09
Subcontractor Only    #808000        2011-08-09
Green                 #008000        2011-08-09
Red                   #ff0000        2012-08-13
Red                   #ff0000        2012-08-13
Brown                 #996633        2013-08-14
Brown                 #996633        2013-08-14
Yellow                #ffff00        2013-08-14
Yellow                #ffff00        2010-08-15
```

These would be loaded into a list of GenericBrandRatingDataObject which gets assigned to the report through an ObjectDataSet

Comment: Unable to replicate on 2008 - can you add a few rows of sample data? Also, what version of SSRS are you using? Finally, not sure if it's anything to do with the issue, but the standard HTML "Green", i.e. what is showing in the Chart area has a hex code of `#008000` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I created it in there so whatever version is the default. The data source is a list of objects I created with three properties: Color, ColorCode, Id. As far as the color code maybe it's not #00FF00 but I meant to indicate I am using six digit color codes with the pound sign preceding them. I'm really confused as to why the colors would work correctly in the graph but not in the legend since they are based on the same formula.

Comment: Are you using default legend box in the chart or did you explicitly created a table for legend? As @IanPreston suggested can you share your raw data for Color, ColorCode?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal I am using the default legend. I wasn't aware you could make a custom one. Maybe that would fix it? As you both requested I have updated the OP with some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer. It seems that when you are doing a series breakout if there is not at least one series item for each group in the data set then the legend shows black. For example in my sample screen shot there are no "Red" ratings in 2010 which is causing the issue.

I updated my data set to return one record for each series/group and just a count of the records instead of each individual record. So for Red/2010 it would have a count of 0. Now each rating has a record in each year and the legend works correctly.